# How to create URL from ASP.Net Web Form class name

Tags: asp.net

I have two classes that inherit from System.Web.UI.Page (two web pages) as seen below.

#### ~/Catalogs/Item.aspx.cs

```
public partial class Item: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink DownloadLink;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I expect this to be "~/Catalogs/Download.aspx"
        // How can I implement this method?
        this.DownloadLink.NavigateUrl = GetTheUrlFor(new Download());
    }
}
```

and

#### ~/Catalogs/Download.aspx.cs

```
public partial class Download : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Perform the download here
    }
}
```

How can I implement the method `GetTheUrlFor(page)` to return the URL for a given Page?

---

*Update1*: this is a ASP.NET Web Application project on .NET 4.5

*Update2*: Request.Url will not work because it gets the URL of the current page but I want the URL of a different page

Comment: Are you talking about [Query String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx)? Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: website or webproject ?

Comment: @Win No, the full URL. I expect this example to return "~/Catalogs/Download.aspx"

Comment: @RoyiNamir web app project

Comment: @styfle The way you are doing is strange in ASP.Net Web Form. Do you know [SessionState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)? The reason I'm asking is I do not know you are asking for a very simple question or complex one. Could you please explain what the reason behind it so that we can suggest you better alternative?

Comment: Will Request.Url.AbsoluteUri not work at this capacity?

Comment: @Win This is a complex question. There is no session that is required. The purpose is to avoid using strings by taking advantage of strong types. I also want to read attributes of the Class however that is not ask that in this question. There is a similar feature for MVC calls T4MVC.

Comment: @DanOrlovsky Request.Url.AbsoluteUri is the URL of the current page...I want the URL of a different page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on my understanding of your question, are you looking for something like this?

```
namespace DemoWebForm
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var path = CreatePathFromType(typeof (Download));
            var url = ResolveUrl(path);
            DownloadLink.NavigateUrl = url;
        }

        private string CreatePathFromType(Type type)
        {
            string fullName = type.FullName; // fullName : DemoWebForm.Catalogs.Download
            var path = Request.ApplicationPath +
                       fullName.Replace("DemoWebForm.", "").Replace(".", "/") +
                       ".aspx";
            return path; // return value: /Catalogs/Download.aspx
        }
    }
}
```